# Nhibernate Bidirectional One-to-one (not HasOne)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to establish a One-to-One relationship (Two-sided References relationship) between two classes. Both Properties should not be nullable. The problem is when you try to save one first over the other, I encounter the Null or Transient value error.

```
class A
{
    C C {get;set;}
}

class C
{
    A A {get;set;}
}


class AMapping : ClassMap<A>
{
    AMapping()
    {
        References(x=>x.C)
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
class CMapping : ClassMap<C>
{
    CMapping()
    {
        References(x=>x.A)
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

I understand that since NHibernate can't make a reference to an object that doesn't exist (in the databaase) yet, but would there be a pattern or a feature that I can use to circumvent this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting cascade="none" on one side of the Many-To-One mapping. Something like:

```
References(x=>x.C)
        .Not.Nullable()
        .Cascade.None();
```

Comment: It's not Many-to-One, just One-to-One

Comment: In fluent NH, References is many to one right? I'm not a fluent NH user, but that's what the docs say here http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#References_.2F_many-to-one